# How to draw big size times like the attached figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]I want to draw similar type of $\times$ using Tikz. Please help me.

Comment: Your question is far from clear. Could you elaborate on what you want exactly, and edit your question to add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to show where you want to draw that *\times*?

Comment: This can be drawn not with a *\times* but by drawing a cross on the right place.

Comment: TikZ can put a `$\times$` anywhere you want.  How are you wanting it to be different than a regular `$\times$`?  Why do you need TikZ?  Does it need to be blue?  Does it need the vertical line you have?  The horizontal line?  How big should it be in relation to other characters?  Where should it be placed in relation to other characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Sorry, your question is not clear ---
- Showed image can be reproduced by following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[cyan, semithick, semitransparent,
      -{Rays[length=2mm 1, sep=0pt -4]}]
        (1,-1) --  (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: in real document you should imit option `semitransparent`. Now is added that position of Rays center is visible.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this usage of `length` and `sep`. Where is it documented? How can you adjust for different line thicknesses?

Comment: Never mind. Found it. Nice solution. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the arrow tip `Rays` from the `arrows.meta` library.

[image]

Lengthening the line the right amount (compensating for the line thickness) is done in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick](0,0)--(1,0);
\draw[thick, blue, -{Rays[length=2mm]}, shorten >=(-.7071mm-.3536*\pgflinewidth)] (.3,-1)--(.3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```